# How to add dynamic property in c#

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to convert my model to JSON in this format,

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { [item.Key] = new { List = item.ToList() }});
```

How to make this (***item*** is `IGrouping<string, object>`)

Comment: Even if you could do that, why you want that? When you access any of the returned objects properties, you allways only get `object`, which needs you to do some annoying casting again and again. Why not just have a class and serialize to that instead? Usually you don´t want to serialize **everything**, but just a well-known set of classes that share some common behaviour - which is expressed by the means of interfaces and abstract classes in .NET. Maybe you can add some data so we have an idea what exactly you want to serialize.

Comment: Because I use consul key-value storage and this area limit max 512 kb per item. I have to group and put my data in the storage.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: well, you can serialize to anonymous: `SerializeObject(new { Key = ..., Value = ... })`. But I won´t use a list as key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If here's a `IGrouping<string, object>` data like

```
var datas = new[] {"A","B","C"}.Select(s => new { key = s, values = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)}).GroupBy(g=>g.key);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datas);
```

and the result by Json.NET Convert SerializeObject json is

```
[[{"key":"A","values":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}],[{"key":"B","values":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}],[{"key":"C","values":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}]]
```

and I think you expect :

```
[[{"A":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}],[{"B":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}],[{"C":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}]]
```

you can use `ToDictionary` to do it like below

```
var datas = new[] { "A", "B", "C" }.Select(s => new { key = s, values = Enumerable.Range(1, 10) }).GroupBy(g => g.key)
    .ToDictionary(v=>v.Key,v=>v.First().values)
;
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datas);
```

result by Json.NET Convert SerializeObject

```
[[{"A":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}],[{"B":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}],[{"C":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}]]
```

Comment: this work 
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Select(c=> new { key = item.Key, value = c }).GroupBy(g => g.key).ToDictionary(v => v.Key, v => v.Select(c=>c.value).ToList()))